# Proguard error, can't export app

Tags: android, proguard

```
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI] Note: there were 208 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getLabelFor()' in class android.view.View
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setLabelFor(int)' in class android.view.View
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-01-25 15:20:55 - CQAQI] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

When I export app I get an error, even after updating to Proguard 4.8. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error message says?

Comment: just one line in config file  -libraryjars libs/jsoup-1.7.1.jar

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I'd be interested in the solution as well.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.view.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
Building with SDK level 4.2.2 worked for me!